# Using iMacros to append text into an input field

Tags: append, imacros

*Note this is for VERSION BUILD=6011206

I'm wondering if anyone knows a script for iMacros that would let you append text into an input field without overwriting anything.

To be more specific, this is for an input box used for notes that I would like to update, without losing any of the previous notes.  Can anyone provide this script?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extract the current value of the text, then set it to a variable then add strings in JavaScript and fill the text field.

```
var macroCurrent;

macroCurrent ="CODE";
macroCurrent +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=some_type ATTR=CLASS:some_class EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";

var macroAppend;

macroAppend ="CODE";
macroAppend +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=some_type ATTR=CLASS:some_class CONTENT={{text}}"+"\n";


var text_to_fill="something here";


iimPlay(macrocurrent)

var text=iimGetLastExtract();

text=text+text_to_fill;

iimSet("text",text)
iimPlay(macroAppend)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe quite long time ago asked, but i stumbled from google so i guess for someone could be useful.
There is simpler way, without using javascript
First extract from field. The flow is like IceD posted, but purely Imacros:
extract field and store to var. append your text to the var. don't forget to clean up variables whenever needed. The code:

```
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:result_box EXTRACT=TXTALL // the text which to append
ADD !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}} // append!
```

Answer (score -1):

When you need to add text in an input you have to do 2 ..
1 - 
recording and the imacros will automatically save and remember this text and add it in the input after the play
2 -
use this code // this is the input of email in facebook
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=ID:login_form ATTR=ID:email CONTENT=-------
change the ------ with your text